# Multiple TextChanged and KeyPress event

Tags: c#

I have a lot of `TextBox` controls. For every `TextBox` control I get their text_Changed and key_Press events. Because of this my Form.cs becomes too crowded. My question is this, is it possible to make this more space free? Some events only consist of one function.

Sample Code:

```
private void txtItem_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    showButtonSave();
}

private void txtItem_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    showButtonSave();
    char ch = e.KeyChar;
    if (ch == (char)Keys.Enter)
    e.Handled = true;
}

private void txtItem2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    showButtonSave();
}

private void txtItem2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    showButtonSave();
    char ch = e.KeyChar;
    if (ch == (char)Keys.Enter)
    e.Handled = true;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `txtItem2` you can go to its properties and there where it says ontextchange you should see it is set to `txtItem2_KeyPress` change that to `txtItem_KeyPress` then they will both use

```
private void txtItem_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
  showButtonSave();
  char ch = e.KeyChar;
  if (ch == (char)Keys.Enter)
  e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: This could be the easiest way and the answer to my problem. thanks for this

Comment: Keep in mind your naming conversion does not really suit this solution. because the method says `txtItem` I would make it something more generic. On top of that also keep in mind if  you do anything in that method both buttons will do the code now. you would however be able to detect which button was pressed using the `sender(object)`

Comment: Thanks for telling me that sir. But I think It will not affect the flow that I wanted. I hope so.

Answer (score 1):

You can create one event for each type(`txtItem_TextChanged` / `txtItem_KeyPress`)and map it to all TextBox. With the help of `sender` you can get the actual control and manipulate as you want.